# Create table type and assign a value to a variable of that type inside of a sproc

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

here is an interesting problem in Sql Server; I have a stored procedure, that returns the following error when executed:

> The type 'MyTable' already exists, or you do not have permission to
>   create it.

I think the type MyTable wasn't properly created, and I base this guess upon the fact other types (nvarchar, for example) are all coloured in blue, whereas when I hover the mouse above @T declaration (DECLARE @T AS MyTable), it says @T has an invalid data type.

Here is a version of the sproc :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPXXX
AS 
BEGIN


DECLARE @calc numeric(18,2)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1500), @column_name nvarchar(50), @table_name nvarchar(50), @prmDef nvarchar(1500)
DECLARE @v1 nvarchar(50), @v2 nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @T AS MyTable

Set @column_name = 'EID'
Set @table_name = 'CTRY_S'
Set @sql = N'Select @calcOUT = SUM(datalength(@v1))/2 from @T';
Set @prmDef = '@v1 nvarchar(50),  @calcOUT numeric(18,2) OUTPUT';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @prmDef, @v1=@column_name, @T=@table_name, @calcOUT=@calc OUTPUT;

END
GO
```

Comment: Refresh your intellisense cache. `Ctrl + Shift + R` from the error message you have posted sounds like it does exist. The procedure you have posted is not valid syntax though. You shouldn't be trying to create this type in the procedure itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of syntax errors in the example code. I am assuming that happened when you shortened the example, so I am not going to talk about them.

Your main problem is, that the `CREATE TYPE MyTable TABLE(..)` command creates an object in the database. This type is not local to the procedure and stays in the database after the procedure finishes. The next time the procedure executes, you will get the error you have seen because the type indeed already exists.

Just remove the create type statement and you should be fine.

As for intellisense, you can never really trust it. Only execution tells if your statement is correct or not. You can use alternatives that are sold by other companies. They tend to be better, but non that I have come across is perfect.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, it's great to know the CREATE TYPE is not local to the sproc - I did a test and was thrilled to confirm this as with every little discovery when you're a newbie. I still however encounter this error: Must declare the table variable "@T". (I am currently playing with the small sproc I posted, when I fix this I will integrate it in a broader context - that's how I usually operate). If you have other flags, please raise them! Thanks.

Comment: Your @permDef string needs to declare all parameters passed. @T is not in there - just add `@T MyTable READONLY`.